# Are there any other wardens like Ned Stark?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Ned Eddard Stark is the Warden of the North. Are there any other warden besides Ned Stark? or It is a special post given to Ned Stark by Robert Baratheon (*like Warden of the East, Warden of the West*)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes there are the wardens of each compass direction, at the start of Game of Thrones those were:

- East: Vacant previously held by Jon Arryn of the Eyrie before his death.
- North: Eddard Stark of Winterfell.
- South: Mace Tyrell of Highgarden.
- West: Tywin Lannister of Casterly Rock.

All these original titles are hereditary as it is a tradition of the house.

Of course over time these positions have changed hands, due to deaths:

> North

- Was inherited by Robb Stark after the death of his father.
- Position was abandoned when Robb rebelled during the War of the Five Kings.
- Position was re-taken by Roose Bolton after the Red Wedding.
- After murdering his father Ramsay Bolton took the position.
- Position was abandoned when Jon beat Ramsay and claimed himself King in the North.
- Jon bends the knee and takes position as Warden of the North to Daenerys though it is not official yet so the position is vacant.

> East

- Robin Arryn inherits the title after the death of his father Jon Arryn.
- The title is officially passed onto Robin by Tywin Lannister to regain their favor.
- As the Arryns appear to have aligned with the Starks it is not clear if Robin still holds the position in the Iron Throne's eyes.

> South

- The position appears to be empty after the death of Mace Tyrell.

> West

- The position is empty after the death of Tywin Lannister.
- Cersei and Tyrion are currently disputing the position.

According to the wiki there are also some minor wardens:

- Warden of the Prince's Pass: Lord Franklyn Fowler.
- Warden of Stone Way: Lord Anders Yronwood.
- Warden of the White Knife: Wyman Manderly of White Harbor.

---

<sup>[Source: awoiaf](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Warden)</sup>

Comment: What about colonies outside Westeros? Do they have wardens?

Comment: @Worse_Username Wardens are used in place where there was once Kings so I doubt it.

Comment: As to the North currently having a vacant position, does that title not apply to Sansa now that she is Lady of Winterfell? She was the next in line to inherit the Stark house (since Bran opted out, and the Boltons' rule over Winterfell has been corrected), so the Warden title should be similarly inherited by Sansa. IIRC, that's also the reason why Sansa got invited to the truce meeting; there would be no other reason to include her, except that she speaks for the North (keep in mind that the Iron Throne does not recognize Jon, but they should recognize the existing Warden).

Comment: @Flater Regarding the Iron Throne they wouldn't recognise anyone yet as they believe the Stark's are traitors to them. Dany recognises Jon as the Warden of the North and the North recognises Jon as the King in the North. So theoretically it is Jon if Dany wins but if Cersei wins it is no one as of yet.

Comment: *when Jon [...] claimed himself King in the North* - Jon didn't claim anything, *the North* made him King.

Comment: @Mat'sMug well that's just a nitpick, he didn't claim it but he accepted it.

Comment: Jon Arryn is not Warden of the East at the beginning of the show - he is already dead at the beginning of the show.

Comment: @TylerH True, been a while since I've watched the beginning.

Comment: Robert also mentions giving the Warden of the East to Jaime when he is talking to Ned.  This is in the early Eddard chapter of Game of Thrones where Robert asks Ned to be the Hand of the King.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**

> Warden is a title bestowed upon the head of a Great House by the ruler of the Seven Kingdoms. The Wardens command the armies of one of the constituent regions of the Seven Kingdoms in the name of Iron Throne for the defense of the entire realm. Thus any one Warden is expected to lawfully command a quarter of all armies in the realm during a time of crisis. - [wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warden)

Same wiki link also list all the wardens till now based on four regions west, east, north and south.

**Prominent one are:**

[Tywin Lannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Tywin_Lannister) as **Warden of the West**, right now it seems there is no Warden in west after his death. Books do mention about Daven Lannister being appointee as warden but in show I don't remember him ever being mentioned yet. Jaime and Tyrion can be contenders but right now Castly Rock region ruler is uncertain. Jamie and Tyrion can get it based on which queen end up being on throne and whom she select. (We don't even know Jaime's clear stance).

Jon Snow as **Warden of the North**, he refereed "himself like that" in his letter to Sansa.

[image]

Image source - [Official GoT twitter account](https://twitter.com/GameOfThrones/status/902664925700530176)

<sub>It can be debated if we can consider post given by Dany or not as she don't sit on Iron Throne yet but Jon write that letter after Cersei agreed with giving there help in upcoming great war (which she denied later to Jaime).</sub>

**Warden of the East:** Lawfully held by Robin Arryn but it's questionable now after their declaration for House Stark and Stark doesn't seems to be in position of making anyone Warden as there king Jon Snow declared Dany there queen, maybe Dany can make Robin Arryn Warden.

**Warden of the South:** post is also vacant for now. And nobody from Tyrell family alive now to claim it, maybe Cersie can appoint a new one.

Comment: Robin Arryn does hold the position of Warden of the East, Tywin re-appointed him to it. Jon Snow isn't the official Warden of the North as per the Iron Throne, I believe the position is vacant.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder that's why I said "he refereed himself like that"  and Tywin is long dead and house Arryn are with North, so Tywin's appointment make no sense now.

Comment: How does it make no sense? He did it for the Iron Throne a position currently held by his family, who was also in charge at the time of the appointment. The position still stands unless stated otherwise which I'm sure hasn't been the case.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder can you mention when Tywin made Robin the Warden? Is it from book or show?

Comment: Both I believe, I'll look for a reference.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder As per my knowledge House Arryn  didn't liked Lanister much and even hold Tyrion as hostage, then they helped keeping Sansa there and even aligned with Stark's now. So don't know how Robin can be considered Warden and I don't remember him being mentioned as such

Comment: I believe Tywin did it to try and get the Arryn's back on his side. But they've never explicitly stated their allegiance though they appear to be pro Stark. We can guess that Cersei revoked the position after the Battle of the Bastards though as it was never stated we can't know for sure so it would appear he holds the position still.

Comment: `Jamie and Tyrion can claim it based on which queen end up being on throne.`: Well Dany would be more inclined to appoint Tyrion but he is her hand and as Jaime appears to have switched sides Jaime would probably get the position, as advised by Tyrion. Though that's speculation of course.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I updated it little further.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is one more other than North one you mentioned.

> Warden is a title bestowed upon the head of a Great House by the ruler of the Seven Kingdoms. The Wardens command the armies of one of the constituent regions of the Seven Kingdoms in the name of Iron Throne for the defense of the entire realm. Thus any one Warden is expected to lawfully command a quarter of all armies in the realm during a time of crisis.

Tyrion Lannister is the Warden of the West. However, position of Warden of the East and South is currently vacant.

[Source](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warden).

> It is also possible that Queen Daenerys Targaryen might recognize her lord hand, **Tyrion Lannister, as Warden of the West** and that she might appoint him to that position should she take the Iron Throne.